# Vite unable to recognize createRouterHash functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, vite

I'm using `createHashRouter` on a vite project for easier deployment to Github Pages. But vite is not recognizing the routes.

Is there any other configuration also required for this? Please see the code below

Home Component

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Home
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

About Component

```
function About() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      About
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import Home from './Home'
import About from './About'
import './index.css'
import { createHashRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    element: <About />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Navigation to work in browser as expected

Comment: didn't get any error ?

Comment: no errors on console/terminal

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:5173/#/about` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:5173/about` or `http://127.0.0.1:5173/#about`

The behaviour was not documented well in react-router which caused the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were using the `createBrowserRouter` basename attribute you will have to remove it in order to make the router works with `createHashRouter`.

It's annoying to add `#` to the path but I didn't find any solution to make it work when deploying. Also in the Vite config you should specify the base url of your app and the `publicDir` to properly load public assets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing an answer. You can take the [tour] to learn more about how SO works. As to your comment about commenting: you need [50 reputation](/help/whats-reputation) to earn the [privilege of commenting everywhere](/help/privileges/comment).